# Displaying XML data in jQuery datatable with Expand and Collapse functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery in my project. I am very new to jQuery and learning the things now. My requirement is to display XML data in datatables and with expand and collapse functionality.

My XML will be something like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <case>
      <case-column-one>case-one</case-column-one>
      <case-column-two>case-two</case-column-two>
      <issue>
         <issue-column-one>issue-one</issue-column-one>
         <issue-column-two>issue-two</issue-column-two>
      </issue>
   </case>
   <case>
      <case-column-three>case-three</case-column-three>
      <case-column-four>case-four</case-column-four>
      <issue>
         <issue-column-three>issue-three</issue-column-three>
         <issue-column-four>issue-four</issue-column-four>
      </issue>
   </case>
</root>
```

Each `<case>` (parent) contains few `<issue>` tags (children). Upon expanding the `<case>`, the children `<issue>` should be opened.

I have to render the above XML data in the jQuery datatable and add expand and collapse functionality to it.
I have gone through the following link and got few things about handling the JSON response.

[jQuery datatable expand and collapse functionality](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

By using the information given in the above link, I am able to render the parent tags `<case>`, but I am not able render the child tags `<issue>` under respective parent tags i.e. `<case>`.

Can anyone help me on this?

The code that I tried is given below:

```js
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").find(".details-control").on("click", function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row

    row.child('<h4>hello</h4>').show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

I just tried to render a hard coded value `hello` in place children. But in reality I have render `<issue>` under `<case>` when it is expanded.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you can try this. http://jsfiddle.net/KQmPb/   Convert XML to JSON

Comment: @ Ashish Kumar, Does that have expand and collapse functionality?

Comment: No..  But once you have the Json ready you can add it easily.. as you are doing in your example

Comment: @AshishKumar,Do you mean that the xml should be converted to json?

Comment: OK..  Limitation wasn't mentioned in question..  and xml data are always plain ....

Comment: @AshishKumar  Do you have any solution for the issue now?

Comment: @AshishKumar Could you please add the answer to the question by converting it to json? I will at least get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a head start . I have taken your sample XML and parse it in JSON Array

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo_jui">
    <table id="events" class="display">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>Issuer</th>

                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var thisTable = $("#events").dataTable();

//Simulated data response
var data = {
    xml: "<root><case><case-column-one>case-one</case-column-one><case-column-two>case-two</case-column-two><issue><issue-column-one>issue-one</issue-column-one><issue-column-two>issue-two</issue-column-two></issue></case><case><case-column-three>case-three</case-column-three><case-column-four>case-four</case-column-four><issue><issue-column-three>issue-three</issue-column-three><issue-column-four>issue-four</issue-column-four></issue></case></root>"
}

$.ajax({
    url:"/echo/xml/",
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success: function(response){
        var $events = $(response).find("case");

        $events.each(function(index, event){
            var $event = $(event),
                addData = [];

            $event.children().each(function(i, child){
                addData.push($(child).text());
            });

            thisTable.fnAddData(addData);
        });
    }
});
```

Working Code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KQmPb/155/)

Comment: Plus one for your suggestion. Sorry for lately responding.